# Strava api vs Google oauth2 library. State token is not returned properly or Google oauth2 library is not processing it properly

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, strava

I'm using the [Google scripts library](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) to establish oauth2 access to the Strava api.  Either the State token is not returned or it is returned but the oauth2 library does not decode it and make it available, I can't tell which.  Both the Strava api and the oauth2 library claim in their documentation to handle the token.

Does anyone have experience of using this mechanism and any pointers to what might be (not) going on?  Or is anyone using this mechanism successfully?

The call is:

```
  var authorisationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl({
    // Pass the additional parameter so that we can identify this callback later
    // but this doesn't seem to work at the moment
    myState: 'additionalParameter'
  });
```

When I examine the data returned from Strava the State part is:

```
state=[ADEpC8xqea0eQC1swItybgXnRDWis5TWp98-5S8BvT6vYxUvUXSu7pUHtp1e_W8RHoW1uB0Iq62H-uOlGuW8Bv8eBf6-9fh7sE2FnLp2jVH3AfqfTR4deGu19JwuaeEl26ztJyKyV49FIEGNWLHFDyAGG1IN_vle5GWQOfox5Z3nSxrRVI0OX9J6ptcW7gv2qlf3nPDBUp-PeAH9ER7MAauwq9HjXZHxiUjy0MB1Mh5s8OBD_35i1eXHnnZAr_PIM0FWqyfhrsxc]
```

which seems reasonable as it's encrypted but when I then try to assign it to a variable with:

```
  function doGet(e) {
    var serviceName = "Completion " + Date();
    var completionService = getService(serviceName);
    var authorised = completionService.handleCallback(e);
    var newState = e.parameter.myState;
}
```

it is undefined.

Ideas?

Comment: It'll be available in your callback function `authCallback` and not in `doGet`

Comment: Have you checked this out? https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/strava-api-with-google-sheets/

Comment: Thank you @TheMaster, it's now fixed.  My error was that was using the optional setRedirectUri parameter when getting the original authorisation url and I was setting it to the url given when the app was published, that url ends in /exec.  deleting that line fixed the whole problem.

Also, thank you Sourabh Choraria, I'd very much recommend the primer by benicollins, it helped me understand things a lot better, thanks for the link.

Comment: Consider adding it as a good answer to help others like you. See [answer].